# Retrieve data datagrid to form

Tags: c#

I have created a form to insert data. When data inserted it shows into datagridview1. I use dataGridView1_MouseClick event to retrieve data into the form. I successfully retrieved textbox data only into my form. I want to retrieve checkbox value which is checked or not. How can i retrieve checkbox value by clicking dataGridView1_MouseClick event.
I use following code for that:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            txtID.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Name.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();                
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
```

[image]

My result is here
But I want like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can retrive values of other fields in similar like u did

This is for WPF control Checkbox [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.checkbox?view=netframework-4.8)

I assume checkbox name of movie is movie_chbox

```
     movie_chbox.IsChecked = 
     dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.toString() == "1" ?true:false
```

Similarly you can do same for other too.

This is for winforms control Checkbox [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_CheckBox_Checked)

```
     movie_chbox.Checked = 
     dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.toString() == "1" ?true:false
```

Comment: It shows checkbox does not contain a definition for Is checked and no extension method Is checked accepting a first argument of type Checkbox could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have update code snippet for both winforms and wpf control checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=netcore-3.1) property of the check box control in your code and change the code for different categories. In your case the final code will be be something like below:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtID.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                string isCheckedMovie = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                string isCheckedSports = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string isCheckedReading = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                string isCheckedWriting = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                if (isCheckedMovie == "1")
                    movieBox.Checked = true;
                else
                    movieBox.Checked = false;

                if (isCheckedSports == "1")
                    sportsBox.Checked = true;
                else
                    sportsBox.Checked = false;

                if (isCheckedReading == "1")
                    readingBox.Checked = true;
                else
                    readingBox.Checked = false;

                if (isCheckedWriting == "1")
                    writingBox.Checked = true;
                else
                    writingBox.Checked = false;
            }
            catch (ApplicationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying 0 or 1 in datagridview display "Interested"/"Not Interested" and when you insert/update to database that time insert/update as 0 or 1 for better database mentainance.